# Case-sensitive files and folders in local git Repository in Mac

Tags: git, macos, github, version-control, operating-system

I am using Mac OS with file system (which has APFS - insensitive file system by default)

Things which I did to make **system adapt to **APFS case-sensitivity**** so that I can access Git repo with case-sensitive files:

1. I created a APFS volume on mac file-system which is case-sensitive and I cloned git repo in this case-sensitive volume which has case-sensitive files.
2. I set git config --global core.ignorecase false

Now, when I have all the files from the git repository locally,

```
    for example: 
    2 files which are pushed from unix OS which same name(case-sensitive) like:
    tmp/circletemp.java 
    tmp/CIRCLETEMP.java
```

I tried to look for case-sensitive files through bash and I can see all the case-sensitive files.

**But** when I do **git ls-files** I cant see the case-sensitive files only one of the file among them is shown.

**Did I missed anything which can help this work on mac?**

***Please help me understand the issue here.***

**thank you for your help:)**

Comment: When you clone in a case sensitive file system, you do not have to adjust `core.ignorecase`. Setting it with `git config --global` is ineffective, but you should not have to set it at all.

Comment: @torek Is there any workaround to make the both the file visible so that I can use these files in the script. I can see these files through bash terminal but when I do git ls-files or open the repo in vscode, other single file in visible.

Comment: Are you sure that both files are in the commit you're extracting? (You can run `git ls-tree -r` on the commit to find out.) If they are both there, there's something wrong with your case-sensitive setup. Try manually making, e.g., files `readme` and `README` and see if you get two different files in your working tree.

Comment: It should have worked with these options which I tried in the question, but it didn't. I did git reset--hard, which helped me to see all the conflicting files in the repo. Correct me if wrong, I guess working tree was not matching the contents of HEAD.

Comment: *"I guess working tree was not matching the contents of HEAD"* - Hard to tell why that might have been the case from what you've said so far, but it does fit the symptoms.